# Android same name issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating my first android app and i have a few layouts so far. In one of them i created a TextView and named it "textViewCurrentUserName". For my surprise, when i created a new layout, inserted a new TextView and try to name it "textViewCurrentUserName" i got a error stating that the name already exists!!! This has got to be a bug right?!? i mean, ok to "no repeat" on the same layout (xml), but these are totally different layouts!!!

Am I doing something wrong here?!? Is there a workaround this??? i dont want to keep a totally idiotic and hard-to-read/understand name such as "activity_UserDetails_TextViewCurrentUserName" and "activity_UserExport_TextViewCurrentUserName"

Comment: It's definitely you. Did you prefix with `@+id`? Post your layout.

Comment: Sometimes, there can be a `<layout>.xml.orig` (or `.xml~` etc) that could also cause that kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android ID field creates a unique ID for each UI element and stores them in the R file. Since fragments/activities and layouts and fairly decoupled, the app itself won't know which layouts and UI elements are available. Thus, you must explicitly state which element you're looking for. The app will throw an exception if the specified UI element is not currently available (or, perhaps, the element will be null).

The only workaround is to develop a naming convention. One might use [fragment-name]_textViewCurrentUser to allow each text view to have a unique ID. Or perhaps you can put a lowercase "t" in front of each UI element that is a text view: [fragment-name]_tCurrentUser.